startRecording(saveDirectory) is not working as expected (cannot retrieve file after ending the recording)
It returns true that it is starting the recording, but when ending the recording it does not save the file in specified saveDirectory
Also checked with File(recordPath).exists() it returns false, no file is saved after ending the recording
Tried flutter_vlc_player to record video/stream footage from drone to flutter app but there is no saved file after recording
Packages used:
(1) https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player
(2) https://github.com/solid-software/flutter_vlc_player.git
I'm using Android platform and here's the code I've tried:
//CameraScreen.dart
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
import 'package:inspek_app/instances/logger.dart';
import 'package:inspek_app/screens/camera/widgets/BottomControls.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CameraScreen> createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
  double zoomStatus = 1;
  bool recording = false;
  String saveDirectory = "";
  final droneSourceUrl = "rtsp://192.168.144.25:8554/main.264";
  final stockSourceUrl =
      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/video/2023/10/12/184734-873923034_large.mp4";
  late final VlcPlayerController _vlcViewController;

  void onZoom() {
    if (zoomStatus != 3) {
      setState(() {
        zoomStatus++;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        zoomStatus = 1;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> startRecording() async {
    bool recordingStarted = false;
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    setState(() {
      recording = true;
      final timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      saveDirectory = '${directory.path}/recordings/$timestamp.mp4';
      logger.i('saveDirectory: $saveDirectory');
    });

    final result = await _vlcViewController.startRecording(
      saveDirectory,
    );
    recordingStarted = result ?? false;
    // final recordingStarted = await FlutterScreenRecording.startRecordScreen(
    //   saveDirectory,
    // );
    if (recordingStarted) {
      logger.i('Recording started: $recordingStarted');
    } else {
      logger.w('Recording have not started');
    }
  }

  Future<void> stopRecording() async {
    setState(() {
      recording = false;
    });
    final recordingStopped = await _vlcViewController.stopRecording();
    if (recordingStopped != null && recordingStopped) {
      logger.i('Recording stopped: $recordingStopped');
      final saveDirectoryFileExists = await File(saveDirectory).exists();
      logger.i("saveDirectoryFileExists: $saveDirectoryFileExists");

      final futures = await Future.wait([
        File(saveDirectory).exists(),
        File("/storage/emulated/0/$saveDirectory").exists(),
        File("/sdcard/$saveDirectory").exists(),
      ]);
      for (var element in futures) {
        logger.i("element: $element");
      }
    } else {
      logger.w('Recording have not stopped');
    }
    // String path = await FlutterScreenRecording.stopRecordScreen;
    // if (path.isNotEmpty) {
    //   logger.i('Recording stopped: $path');
    //   final saveDirectoryFileExists = await File(path).exists();
    //   logger.i("saveDirectoryFileExists: $saveDirectoryFileExists");
    // } else {
    //   logger.w('Recording have not stopped');
    // }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _vlcViewController = VlcPlayerController.network(
      droneSourceUrl,
      autoPlay: true,
      autoInitialize: true,
      hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
      options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
    );

    _vlcViewController.addOnInitListener(() {
      logger.i('_vlcViewController init');
    });
    _vlcViewController.addOnRendererEventListener((p0, p1, p2) {
      logger.i('p0=$p0, p1=$p1, p2=$p2');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    await _vlcViewController.stopRecording();
    await _vlcViewController.stopRendererScanning();
    await _vlcViewController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1;

    void notifyRecordingStarted() {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Recording started'),
        ),
      );
    }

    void notifyRecordingEnded() {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Recording ended'),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SizedBox(
        height: height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.87,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: VlcPlayer(
                controller: _vlcViewController,
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                placeholder: const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.13,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: BottomControls(
                recording: recording,
                onRecord: () async {
                  if (!recording) {
                    await startRecording();
                    notifyRecordingStarted();
                  } else {
                    await stopRecording();
                    notifyRecordingEnded();
                    final recordPath = _vlcViewController.value.recordPath;
                    logger.i('recordPath=$recordPath');
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


What do you log statements say?  Have you tried ensuring that the destination directory exists before calling startRecording?  The documentation doesn't indicate if it will or won't create the destination directory automatically.
